# How to vertically align responsive image in css

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, vertical-alignment

I am having a problem to center vertically a responsive image inside its container.

I have tried a few things but those are works on fixed size, not in responsive.

I am using Bootstrap 4.

Below my code and an attempt with line-height

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 img-container" style="line-height:100%">
      <img src="sample.jpg" alt="Sample" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap, you can add `d-flex align-items-center` to your `col-md-7` div. This will force the column to use [CSS flex box for layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and align-items-center tells the content to vertically positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. For the container of the image write the following code

```
.yourContainer{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
```

}

Comment: I have tried it before, the image is stretching its height.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it yourself, you can try this.
First you have to add other class for the container of the image

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 wrapper-img" style="line-height:100%">
            <img src="sample.jpg" alt="Sample" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in style.css

```
.wrapper-img{   
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It also worked thanks for giving your important time

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap comes with buil-in class that you can use , d-flex on the col and m-auto on img will do :

```css
.row {border:solid}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 d-flex " style="line-height:100%">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=sample.jpg" alt="Sample" class="img-fluid m-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aperiam, sit placeat corporis architecto praesentium facere aut rem quis odio ab voluptates sunt, eum harum ipsam, fugit numquam aliquid laboriosam.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ & https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps the most.